# nodejs request post large json fail

Tags: node.js, http

I am trying to post large json to a http server(a grafana server actually):

here is my code:

```
const http = require('http')
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')
const opts = {
    hostname: 'myip',
    port: 3000,
    path: '/api/dashboards/uid/KPEiIQVWk',
    method: 'GET',
    timeout: 5000,
    headers : {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ********************************************',
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
}
const req = http.request(opts, res => {
    console.log(`Fetch: statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    var origin = ''
    res.on('data', d => {
        origin += d
    })

    res.on('end', function(){
        dash = JSON.parse(origin)
        dash.dashboard.panels.forEach(p => {
            if(p.id == 26){
                fs.readFile(__dirname + '/grafana/pm/branch-graph.html','utf-8', function(err, newPanel){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    p.content = newPanel
                    const fresh = JSON.stringify(dash)
                    const updateOptions = {
                        uri: 'http://myip:3000/api/dashboards/db',
                        method: 'post',
                        headers : {
                            'Authorization' : 'Bearer *************************',
                             'Accept' : 'application/json',
                             'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                             'Content-length' : fresh.length
                       },
                       json: fresh
                    }
                    fs.writeFile('tmp.json', fresh, function(err){
                        if(err){
                            console.error(err)
                        }
                    })

                    request(updateOptions, function(error, response, body){
                        console.log(`update: statusCode=${response.statusCode}`)
                        console.log(`update: ${body}`)
                    })
                })
            }
        })

    })
})

req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error)
})

req.on('timeout', () => {
    req.abort()
})

req.end()
```

as you can see, I first fetch a grafana dashboard's source, then make some udpate, then post it back to grafana server. but always get 400 error. The strange thing is that if I dump the json to a file and use curl to post, it will work.

```
curl -vH "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Expect:" -d @tmp.json -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://myip:3000/api/dashboards/db
```

the whole json is about 40000+ bytes. any hint on this? I am not very famillar with nodejs. I am just trying to write some CI scripts.

Comment: problem solved, the content-length shoud be `Buffer.byteLength(fresh, 'utf-8')`, silly mistake by myself

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think it's necessary to use both the `http` and `request` modules. `http` is a module built into nodejs, and `request` is an npm package.

I recommend you use the npm request package because it's easier. You can read its documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication

Second, the options you're passing to the request module is not formatted correctly, I think this is why it is not working. With your current code, I would `console.log('POST error', error);` to print out the error. The correct options for the `request` module is proposed below.

```
const options = {
    url: 'https://myip:3000/api/dashboards/db',
    body: fresh, // the json from the fs.read callback
    auth: {
         'bearer': 'bearerToken'
    },
    json: true // from docs: If json is true, then body must be a JSON-serializable object.
}
request.post(
    options,
    (err, httpResponse, body) => {
       console.log(err, body);
});
```